# Need some weird time conversion with SQLite query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite database, with columns `time`, `name`, `value`.

The `time` column is storing epoch in seconds, like "1695765399" and it is recorded every one second.

There will be a scheduled trigger to run this query at NZST 12:05 (midnight), +5 minutes to give a bit space for SQLite database to record the data. For each unique `name`, I need to get the exactly 12:00:00 NZST time in `time` column (epoch in sec) 5 min ago (in SQLite database, no any second will missing). And output as UTC '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ' format.

Create data:

```py
import sqlite3
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

conn = sqlite3.connect('your_database.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Create the table
c.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE your_table (
        name TEXT,
        value REAL,
        time INTEGER
    )
''')

# Start time at 11:55pm
start_time = datetime.now().replace(hour=23, minute=55, second=0)

# Insert data from 11:55pm to 12:10am
for i in range((10 + 5) * 60):  # 10 minutes before and 5 minutes after midnight
    current_time = start_time + timedelta(seconds=i)
    epoch_time = int(current_time.timestamp())
    for name in ['1', '2', '3']:
        value = random.random()
        c.execute('INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (name, value, epoch_time))

# Commit the changes and close the connection
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Result I expected:

```
utc_time             name           value
------------------------------------------
xxxxx11:00:00         1              100
xxxxx11:00:00         2              200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following can be the basis.

- There are some things in your question that don't appear to match up, e.g. %H is the hour in 24 hour, midnight is actual 00:00:00 the next day.

Anyway perhaps the following could be the basis for what it appears you want.

- Note that additional data has been included in the resultant output, in the hope of helping to understand various aspects.

The query on it's own:-

```
WITH local_utc_modifier(lum) AS 
    /* CTE (Common Table Expression a temp table) with the difference between local and utc (not sure - is correct but principle IF device is setup accordingly)*/
    (SELECT (strftime('%s','now','localtime')) - (strftime('%s','now','UTC')))
SELECT
    name,
    (SELECT lum FROM local_utc_modifier) AS lum , /* the modifier value: include to demonstrate  <<<<<<<<<<EXTRA>>>>>>>>>>*/ 
    strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ',time,'unixepoch','-'||(SELECT * FROM local_utc_modifier)||' seconds') /* output value */ AS time,
    value, /* NOTE ARBRITRAY */
    max(value) AS maxv, /* include to demonstrate arbrtrary value <<<<<<<<<<EXTRA>>>>>>>>>>*/
    min(value) AS minv, /* as prev <<<<<<<<<<EXTRA>>>>>>>>>>*/
    avg(value) AS avgv, /* as prev <<<<<<<<<<EXTRA>>>>>>>>>>*/
    count() AS number_found /* more than 1!!!! SEE ABOVE RESULTS <<<<<<<<<<EXTRA>>>>>>>>>> */
    
FROM your_table
/* Only midnight rows to a second */
WHERE strftime('%H:%M:%S',time,'unixepoch','-'||(SELECT * FROM local_utc_modifier)||' seconds') = '00:00:00'
    /* MIGHT WANT ADDITIONAL CONDITION JUST FOR CURRENT DATE */
/* Note if only 1 row per name then no need for GROUP BY HOWEVER MUST NOT THEN HAVE aggregate functions (count,max,min,avg) */
GROUP BY name
;
```

- **See the comments** as there are parts of the query that you probably do not want/need.

A demo  of the above:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS your_table;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS your_table (
        name TEXT,
        value REAL,
        time INTEGER
);

/* Insert some testing data */
INSERT INTO your_table (name,value,time) 
    VALUES
    (1,100,1695765399),(2,200,1695765405),(3,300,1695765410),(3,10,1695765415),(2,20,1695765420),
    /* these ones are at midnight*/
    (1,100,1695765420 + 180),(1,15,1695765600),(2,222,1695765600),(3,333,1695765600),
    /* 1 second past midnight */
    (5,555,1695765601)
    ;
SELECT name, value, datetime(time,'unixepoch') AS easyreadtime, time FROM your_table;
WITH local_utc_modifier(lum) AS 
    /* CTE (Common Table Expression a temp table) with the difference between local and utc (not sure - is correct but principle IF device is setup accordingly)*/
    (SELECT (strftime('%s','now','localtime')) - (strftime('%s','now','UTC')))
SELECT
    name,
    (SELECT lum FROM local_utc_modifier) AS lum , /* the modifier value: include to demonstrate  <<<<<<<<<<EXTRA>>>>>>>>>>*/ 
    strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ',time,'unixepoch','-'||(SELECT * FROM local_utc_modifier)||' seconds') /* output value */ AS time,
    value, /* NOTE ARBRITRAY */
    max(value) AS maxv, /* include to demonstrate arbrtrary value <<<<<<<<<<EXTRA>>>>>>>>>>*/
    min(value) AS minv, /* as prev <<<<<<<<<<EXTRA>>>>>>>>>>*/
    avg(value) AS avgv, /* as prev <<<<<<<<<<EXTRA>>>>>>>>>>*/
    count() AS number_found /* more than 1!!!! SEE ABOVE RESULTS <<<<<<<<<<EXTRA>>>>>>>>>> */
    
FROM your_table
/* Only midnight rows to a second */
WHERE strftime('%H:%M:%S',time,'unixepoch','-'||(SELECT * FROM local_utc_modifier)||' seconds') = '00:00:00'
    /* MIGHT WANT ADDITIONAL CONDITION JUST FOR CURRENT DATE */
/* Note if only 1 row per name then no need for GROUP BY HOWEVER MUST NOT THEN HAVE aggregate functions (count,max,min,avg) */
GROUP BY name
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS your_table; /* CLEANUP DEMO ENVIRONMENT */
```

- **Important** the above has been used in AEST time so the difference in time zone would need to be considered with regard to the testing data.
  When the above is run then the **Results** are:-
- The data that was loaded the 1st **SELECT** :-

[image]

```
- note the 2 highlighted name **1** rows both are at midnight (to demonstrate GROUP BY and aggregate functions)
```

- The result, along the lines of an interpretation of your question:-

[image]

- The 2nd column is an extra just to show you the time difference between local and utc according to the device (AEST time).
- the last four columns demonstrate aggregate functions grouping.

**Aggregate Functions and GROUP BY**

For the name 1 the number_found (from the `count` function) shows that there were 2 rows that matched the WHERE criteria (probably note the case wanted).

The GROUP BY clause defines sets of rows that are to be treated as a group that the aggregate functions apply to, noting that for a group 1 row will be output. (hence the 3 outputs for included names, name 5 is out by a second for inclusion).

- Omit the GROUP BY clause and all the output is considered as 1 group if any aggregate function is used, resulting 1 row output.

If a column is chosen to be output and it's is not subject to an aggregate expression then the value extracted  will be a value from one of the rows in the group. It is an arbitrary value (e.g. for the value column `15` was extracted, it could have been `100`) (The max, min and avg values demonstrate).

- The arbitrary value(s), will be from the first value, according to how the query optimizer decides to process the rows. Unless delving into the depths of understanding the optimizer, it is probably best to not rely upon an such a value.

**Additional**

Think about the matter although the following is more complex, it is a demo that perhaps makes things easier to understand and also provides options that can be taken.

It is similar to the original demo, BUT loads data:-

- 10000 rows with:-

  - names 1-10,
  - values 1-100,
  - and times that are (locally) with 1 minute of midnight.

    - Some will be midnight exactly (unless very unlucky as there's 1 in 60 chance of hitting midnight)

The original query has been added to to show various aspects (the assumption is that UTC time is used when storing the data).

One thing that it clearly shows is that there is no need to come up with lum (local UTC modifier), just 'UTC' or not OR 'localtime' is all that is needed (the device/sqlite knows the modifier already).

So here's the more in-depth (now that I not half asleep) version:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS your_table;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS your_table (
        name TEXT,
        value REAL,
        time INTEGER
);
/* populate table with 10000 rows (as per LIMIT) 
    with names 1-10 (random), 
    random values 1-1000, and 
    date and time as per the current date at 00:00:?? 
        where ?? is 0 - 59 seconds after midnight
*/
WITH 
    cte_counter(x) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT x + 1 FROM cte_counter LIMIT 10000)
-- SELECT * FROM cte_counter;
    INSERT INTO your_table SELECT
        (abs(random()) % 10) + 1 /* 1 to 10 */  AS name,
        (abs(random()) % 1000) + 1 /* 1 to 1000 */ AS value,
        
        /* get the current date, apply the time as 00:00:00 (midnight) and store as UTC time */ 
        strftime('%s',(date('now')||'T00:00:00'),'UTC','+'||(abs(random()) % 60)||' seconds') AS time FROM cte_counter
;
SELECT *,datetime(time,'unixepoch','UTC') AS UTCTime, datetime(time,'unixepoch','localtime') FROM your_table;


/* PROCESS THE LOADED DATA */
WITH local_utc_modifier(lum) AS 
    /* CTE (Common Table Expression a temp table) with the difference between local and utc (not sure - is correct but principle IF device is setup accordingly)*/
    (SELECT (strftime('%s','now','localtime')) - (strftime('%s','now','UTC')))
SELECT
    name, /* AS IS */
    /* the modifier value: included to demonstrate (note should not be 79200 for NZ that is AEST difference) <<<<<<<<<<EXTRA>>>>>>>>>>*/
    (SELECT lum FROM local_utc_modifier) AS lum , /* the modifier value: included to demonstrate (note should not be 79200 for NZ that is AEST difference) <<<<<<<<<<EXTRA>>>>>>>>>>*/ 
    /* The stored time as local time (you would expect 00:00:??)*/
    strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ',time,'unixepoch','localtime') AS time,
    /* The stored time as per UTC time */
    strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ',time,'unixepoch','UTC') /* output value */ AS AlternateTime,
    /* The unadjusted stored time. EXPECT IT TO MATCH ALTERATETIME (to confirm data stored as UTC, if stored as LOCAL then SQL has to be changed)*/
    strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ',time,'unixepoch') AS UATime,
    value, /* NOTE WHEN GROUPED THIS WILL BE AN ARBRITRAY VALUE */
    max(value) AS maxv, /* include to demonstrate arbrtrary value <<<<<<<<<<EXTRA>>>>>>>>>>*/
    min(value) AS minv, /* as prev <<<<<<<<<<EXTRA>>>>>>>>>>*/
    avg(value) AS avgv, /* as prev <<<<<<<<<<EXTRA>>>>>>>>>>*/
    count() AS number_found /* more than 1!!!! SEE ABOVE RESULTS <<<<<<<<<<EXTRA>>>>>>>>>> */
    /* LOOK AT JUST THE TIME PORTION (as exactly 00:00:00 is wanted e.g. NOT 00:00:01)*/
    , strftime('%H:%M:%S',time,'unixepoch','localtime') AS loctime
    , strftime('%H:%M:%S',time,'unixepoch','UTC') AS UTCtime
    /* No need for this calculation, localtime should be good but as proof of concept- */
    , strftime('%H:%M:%S',time,'unixepoch','UTC','+'||(SELECT * FROM local_utc_modifier)||' seconds') AS timeonly
    /* just get the hours in the day, if midnoght then 0 (prehaps the most efficient way) */
    , strftime('%s',time,'unixepoch','localtime') % (60 * 60 * 24) AS hoursAsInt
FROM your_table
/* Only midnight rows to a second */
/* NOTE could use various means of detcting midnight rows only e.g. :-
    the simpler strftime('%H:%M:%S',time,'unixepoch','localtime') = '00:00:00' 
    or even strftime('%s',time,'unixepoch','localtime') % (60 * 60 * 24) = 0
    see above and output for results of the left side of the expression
    */
WHERE strftime('%H:%M:%S',time,'unixepoch','UTC','+'||(SELECT * FROM local_utc_modifier)||' seconds') = '00:00:00'
    /* MIGHT WANT ADDITIONAL CONDITION JUST FOR CURRENT DATE */
/* Note if only 1 row per name then no need for GROUP BY HOWEVER MUST NOT THEN HAVE aggregate functions (count,max,min,avg) */
GROUP BY name
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS your_table;
```

- A suggestion is to drop the above into an SQLite Tool (Navicat was used) and play with the code/SQL.

Comment: How can I specify the local time with NZST instead of 'localtime', or I dont need to maybe?

Comment: using those `INSERT INTO your_table (name,value,time) 
    VALUES
    (1,100,1696244400),(2,200,1696244400),(3,300,1696244400),(3,10,1696244400),(2,20,1696244400),
    (1,100,1696244401),(1,15,1696244401),(2,222,1696244401),(3,333,1696244401), (5,555,1696244401)
 ;` but not work

Comment: @Yiffany localtime, if the devices are setup for NZST should probably reflect the time. The examples were done using AEST (Sydney time), so the values will need to be adjusted to match (Using SavvyTime it appears that NZST is 3 hours ahead of AEST) so adjusting by 3 * 60 * 60 would adjust the time(I believe). Really the answer is in-principle rather than specific to your time zone (wasn't going to reset my computers time zone). What I did was adjust the values to suit so 1695765600 = midnight 26/09/2023 AEST.

Comment: @Yiffany the answer has been updated with a perhaps more flexible and more informative demo.